# How to match two different array set and update non matched object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two different arrays of the object(SquadDetails,powerDetails).

I have to match the following condition

```
SquadDetails.memberswithpower.id == powerDetails.id and SquadDetails.memberswithpower.powers = powerDetails.powers/ SquadDetails.memberswithpower.name= powerDetails.name
```

How can match id and powers/name? if not matched add that object into powerDetails.

could someone advise on this?

```js
var SquadDetails = [{
  "squadName": "Super hero squad",
  "homeTown": "Metro City",
  "formed": 2016,
  "memberswithpower": [
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "powers": "Radiation resistance"
      
    },
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "powers":"Turning tiny"
     
    }
  ]
},
{
  "squadName": "ABC squad",
  "homeTown": "ABC",
  "formed": 2017,
  "memberswithpower": [
    {
      "id":2,
      "name": "Eternal Flame",
      "powers": "Radiation resistance"
      
    }
  ]
},
{
  "squadName": "XYZ squad",
  "homeTown": "XYZ",
  "formed": 2017,
  "memberswithpower": [
    {
      "id":3,
      "name": "Madame Uppercut",
      "powers": "Radiation resistance"
      
    }
  ]
},
{
  "squadName": "wsx squad",
  "homeTown": "XYZ",
  "formed": 2018,
  "memberswithpower": []
}
];

var powerDetails = [
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "powers": "Radiation resistance"
      
    },
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "powers":"Radiation blast"
     
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "name": "Eternal Flame",
      "powers":"Turning tiny"
      
    }
  ]

console.log(SquadDetails);

var filter = 

  SquadDetails.filter(SD => 
  
        <!-- SD.memberswithpower.filter(MWP => -->
            <!-- console.log(MWP.id) -->
            
                <!-- <!-- powerDetails.filter(PD =>  --> -->
                   <!-- <!-- PD.id == MWP.id && PD.powers == MWP.powers --> -->
                
                <!-- <!-- ) --> -->

        <!-- )   -->
        
        SD.some(function (arrVal) {
            console.log(arrVal)
        });
)
```

Expected output:

```
[
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "powers": "Radiation resistance"
      
    },  
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "powers":"Turning tiny"
     
    },
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "powers":"Radiation blast"
         
    }
    {
      "id":2,
      "name": "Eternal Flame",
      "powers": "Radiation resistance"
      
    }
    {
      "id":2,
      "name": "Eternal Flame",
      "powers":"Turning tiny"
      
    },
    {
      "id":3,
      "name": "Madame Uppercut",
      "powers": "Radiation resistance"
      
    }
  ]
```

I have tried filter and some methods but getting errors. could someone help me with this?

[image]

I have a table with 3 rows shown above(SquadDetails)

1. 1st row 1st column Molecule Man/Radiation resistance
2. 1st-row 2nd column Molecule Man/Radiation blast
3. 2nd row 1st column Eternal Flame/Turning tiny

Now I have to compare `Powerdetails` with `SquadDetails` and I have to update non matched row in the Powerdetails which means(based on provided data) I have to add

1. 1st-row 3rd column Molecule Man/Turning tiny

Explanation:  In 1st row `{"id":1, "name": "Molecule Man", "powers":"Turning tiny"}`  is not matching so we have to add this in 1st row

2. 2nd row 2nd column Eternal Flame/Radiation resistance

Explanation: In the 2nd row below item is not matching so we have to add this in 2nd row

```
{"id":2,"name": "Eternal Flame","powers":"Radiation resistance"}
```

2. 3rd row 1st column Madame Uppercut/Radiation resistance

Explanation: In the 3rd row below item is not present so we have to add this in 3rd row

```
{"id":3,"name": "Madame Uppercu","powers":"Radiation resistance"}
```

Comment: @MisterJojo memberswithpower[x].id is unique . name can not be a unique value. the same name can be used in different squadName.

Comment: power details example:[
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "powers": "Radiation resistance"
      
    },
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "powers":"Radiation blast"
     
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "name": "Eternal Flame",
      "powers":"Turning tiny"
      
    }
  ]

Comment: NO it's not same .we can have different scnerio like this 

[
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "powers": "Radiation resistance"
      
    },
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "powers":"Turning tiny"
     
    },
 {
      "id":1,
      "name": "ABC",
      "powers":"Turning tiny"
     
    }
  ]

Comment: In this case I do not believe that your problem is solvable, because the logic of your data is inconsistent.

Comment: @MisterJojo how to resolve this ?

Comment: @MisterJojo I don't think this is an illogical problem. could you please take a look at my pic?

Comment: you say IDs are unique, but that's not true: there are already 2 `id:1` in the first `memberswithpower` and you want to add `2-1`, which will make `3` ID. same for the second `memberswithpower` where you want to add a second one. Then you indicate that this ID can be associated with different `names` in any possible scenario...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply achieve this with a minimal development effort by comparing the JSON strings (Convert the objects into  string) by using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and then check the index in the of the JSON string into `powerDetails` string.

Live Demo **:**

```js
var SquadDetails = [{
  "squadName": "Super hero squad",
  "homeTown": "Metro City",
  "formed": 2016,
  "memberswithpower": [
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "powers": "Radiation resistance"

    },
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "powers":"Turning tiny"

    }
  ]
}, {
  "squadName": "ABC squad",
  "homeTown": "ABC",
  "formed": 2017,
  "memberswithpower": [
    {
      "id":2,
      "name": "Eternal Flame",
      "powers": "Radiation resistance"

    }
  ]
}, {
  "squadName": "XYZ squad",
  "homeTown": "XYZ",
  "formed": 2017,
  "memberswithpower": [
    {
      "id":3,
      "name": "Madame Uppercut",
      "powers": "Radiation resistance"

    }
  ]
}, {
  "squadName": "wsx squad",
  "homeTown": "XYZ",
  "formed": 2018,
  "memberswithpower": []
}];

var powerDetails = [{
  "id":1,
  "name": "Molecule Man",
  "powers": "Radiation resistance"
}, {
  "id":1,
  "name": "Molecule Man",
  "powers":"Radiation blast"
}, {
  "id":2,
  "name": "Eternal Flame",
  "powers":"Turning tiny"
}];

SquadDetails.forEach(({ memberswithpower }) => {
    memberswithpower.forEach(obj => {
    if (JSON.stringify(powerDetails).indexOf(JSON.stringify(obj)) === -1) {
        powerDetails.push(obj);
    }
  })
});

console.log(powerDetails);
```